# Fault Sequence ERROR_CODE property is not generating error as expected in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When working with the log mediator, it is generating error code as '0' for all the errors. Is not working as expected. 
`<log level="custom">
<property name="text" value="An unexpected error occured"/>
<property name="message" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>

</log>`

Answer (score 0):

have configured the property with a name ERROR_CODE before using it log mediator. if not create the same using proper expression from the response body.